# How to add number from html to custom data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML snippet that is repeated through the page. I would like to take a number from that single snippet and add it as a custom data attribute to div with a single-book class.

```
<div class="books row">
   <div class="col-md-2 single-book">
 <p class="title">Hippie</p>
 <span>2018</span>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-2 single-book">
   <p class="title">Alchemist</p>
   <span>2015</span>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-2 single-book">
  <p class="title">The Spy</p>
  <span>2017</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to take a number value, and add it through jquery as a custom data-year attribute

```
var num = $('.single-book span').text();
$('.single-book').attr('data-year',num)
```

But the problem is that this code took all values 2018,2015,2017 and it as data-year="201820152017". and should be data-year="2018" for first, data-year="2015" for a second etc

What am I missing, any hint, please? Thanks.

Comment: Your JQuery code is targeting all the span elements with the class of .single-book. If you want to apply each year to a specific value, consider adding an id to the span and adding it back accordingly.

Comment: Try This 

$(".single-book").attr("data-year",function() {
  return $(this).find("span").text()
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are targeting all span elements and then all single-book elements. You need to make sure they belong together:

```
$('.single-book').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-year',$(this).find('span').text())
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".single-book").attr("data-year",function() {
  return $(this).find("span").text()
});
```

This will add the `attribute` `data-year` to each `.single-book` element with the value from the `span` inside it.

**Working demo**

```js
$(".single-book").attr("data-year",function() {
  return $(this).find("span").text()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="books row">
  <div class="col-md-2 single-book">
    <p class="title">Hippie</p>
    <span>2018</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 single-book">
    <p class="title">Alchemist</p>
    <span>2015</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 single-book">
    <p class="title">The Spy</p>
    <span>2017</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you.

```js
 $('.single-book').each(function(){
   let num=$(this).find('span').text();
  $(this).attr('data-year',num);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="books row">
   <div class="col-md-2 single-book">
 <p class="title">Hippie</p>
 <span>2018</span>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-2 single-book">
   <p class="title">Alchemist</p>
   <span>2015</span>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-2 single-book">
  <p class="title">The Spy</p>
  <span>2017</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through all the elements to set the attribute. I prefer [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute in this case:

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

```js
$('.single-book').each(function(){
  $(this).data('year', $(this).find('span').text());
  console.log($(this).data('year')); // test
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="books row">
   <div class="col-md-2 single-book">
   <p class="title">Hippie</p>
   <span>2018</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 single-book">
   <p class="title">Alchemist</p>
   <span>2015</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 single-book">
  <p class="title">The Spy</p>
  <span>2017</span>
  </div>
</div>
```